# DateTime.AddMonths adding only month not days

Tags: c#, datetime

Let's say I have **28th of February 2010** and add one month to this date using `AddMonths(1)`. The resulting date is **March 28th**, but not **31st of March**, which I want.
Is there a way to tweak that a bit so this works without adding custom code?

Edit: I don't need the last day of a month, actually I need to add one month, but when its the last day of a month, I need to find the last day of the next month.

Comment: If any answer meets your needs please hit the "tick" next to it to accept it.

Comment: To finetune the algorithm: And what do you expect when the date is 27 february or 1 february?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I don't know what you want to achieve, but you could add one day, add a month and subtract one day.

```
DateTime nextMonth = date.AddDays(1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

**EDIT**:

As one of the commenters points out, this sometimes gives the wrong result. After reading your updated question, I think the easiest way of calculating the date you want is:

```
public static DateTime NextMonth(this DateTime date)
{
   if (date.Day != DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month))
      return date.AddMonths(1);
   else 
      return date.AddDays(1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
}
```

This extension method returns next month's date. When the current date is the last day of the month, it will return the last day of next month.

Comment: Clever - that would work if he's guaranteed to have the last day of the month already.

Comment: If he doesn't, the result is the same as AddMonths(1)

Comment: For the 30th of January, it isn't.

Comment: Any solution for the the 30th of January?

Comment: Why not just new Date(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1) in else?

Answer (score 14):

```
public static DateTime NextMonth(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime nextMonth = date.AddMonths(1);

    if (date.Day != DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month)) //is last day in month
    {
        //any other day then last day
        return nextMonth;
    }
    else
    {
       //last day in the month will produce the last day in the next month
       return date.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month));
    }
}
```

And generalized for multiple months:

```
public static DateTime AddMonthToEndOfMonth(DateTime date, int numberOfMonths)
{
    DateTime nextMonth = date.AddMonths(numberOfMonths);

    if (date.Day != DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month)) //is last day in month
    {
        //any other day then last day
        return nextMonth;
    }
    else
    {
        //if date was end of month, add remaining days
        int addDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month) - nextMonth.Day;
        return nextMonth.AddDays(addDays);
    }
}
```

The code is tested against February issues, leap year and New Year transition. All test passed.

[image]

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddMonthTest_January()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 2, i), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 1, i)));
    }
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 2, 28), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 1, 29)));
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 2, 28), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 1, 30)));
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 2, 28), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 1, 31)));
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddMonthTest_February()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 3, 31), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 2, 28)));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 27; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 3, i), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 2, i)));
    }            
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddMonthTest_March()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 4, 30), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 3, 31)));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 4, i), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 3, i)));
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddMonthTest_December()
{            
    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 1, i), NextMonth(new DateTime(2015, 12, i)));
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddMonthTest_January_LeapYear()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 29; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 2, i), NextMonth(new DateTime(2016, 1, i)));
    }            
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 2, 29), NextMonth(new DateTime(2016, 1, 30)));
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 2, 29), NextMonth(new DateTime(2016, 1, 31)));
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddMonthTest_February_LeapYear()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 3, 31), NextMonth(new DateTime(2016, 2, 29)));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 3, i), NextMonth(new DateTime(2016, 2, i)));
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddHalfYearTest_January_LeapYear()
{        
    for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 7, i), new DateTime(2016, 1, i).AddMonthToEndOfMonth(6));
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddHalfYearTest_February_LeapYear()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 8, 31), new DateTime(2016, 2, 29).AddMonthToEndOfMonth(6));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 8, i), new DateTime(2016, 2, i).AddMonthToEndOfMonth(6));
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void AddHalfYearTest_December()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 6, 30), new DateTime(2015, 12, 31).AddMonthToEndOfMonth(6));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2016, 6, i), new DateTime(2015, 12, i).AddMonthToEndOfMonth(6));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you mean that the resultant date should be the same distance from the **end** of the month, then you're into custom code - something like (not fully tested, especially re 28/30/31 months):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var when = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime fromEndOfNextMonth = when.AddMonthsRelativeToEndOfMonth(1);
    }
    
}
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime AddMonthsRelativeToEndOfMonth(
               this DateTime when, int months)
    {
        if (months == 0) return when;
        DateTime startOfNextMonth = when;
        int month = when.Month;
        while (startOfNextMonth.Month == month)
        {
            startOfNextMonth = startOfNextMonth.AddDays(1);
        }
        TimeSpan delta = startOfNextMonth - when;
        return startOfNextMonth.AddMonths(months) - delta;
    }

}
```

Comment: The last line of the extension method should be `return startOfNextMonth.AddMonths(months) - delta;`

Answer (score 4):

How about like this? It solves the Jan 30th problem that would occur with the current best answer.

```
public static DateTime AddJustMonths(this DateTime @this, int months)
{
  var firstDayOfTargetMonth = new DateTime(@this.Year, @this.Month, 1).AddMonths(months);
  var lastDayofTargetMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(firstDayOfTargetMonth.Year, firstDayOfTargetMonth.Month);

  var targetDay = @this.Day > lastDayofTargetMonth ? lastDayofTargetMonth : @this.Day;

  return new DateTime(firstDayOfTargetMonth.Year, firstDayOfTargetMonth.Month, targetDay);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will add the number of months and will jump to the last day of the target month if the current day is the last day of the current month. Note that there is **fundamentally no solution** to the problem of January 30 without doing fully custom dates:

If the date is the only state, then no matter how you handle the one month jump ahead from January 30, you have to chose if you interpret the result as *the last day of February* or simply the *28th of the current month*. You can't have both since the date is your only state. There is no 'flag' which tells you that *this very 28th of February was originally the single to last day in January*.

Effectively this means that Jan30.AddMonthsCustom(1).AddMonthsCustom(1) != Jan30.AddMonthsCustom(2) and that eventually any 30th, 29th and 28th date ends up on the last day of the month if you keep propagating.

```
public static DateTime AddMonthsCustom(this DateTime date, int months)
{

    // Check if we are done quickly.
    if(months == 0)
        return;

    // Lookup the target month and its last day.
    var targetMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(months);
    var lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(targetMonth.Year, targetMonth.Month);

    // If we are starting out on the last day of the current month, then jump
    // to the last day of the target month.
    if (date.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month))
        return new DateTime(targetMonth.Year, targetMonth.Month, lastDay);

    // If the target month cannot accomodate the current day, jump to the 
    // last day of the target month.
    if (date.Day > lastDay)
        return new DateTime(targetMonth.Year, targetMonth.Month, lastDay);

    // Simply jump to the current day in the target month.
    return new DateTime(targetMonth.Year, targetMonth.Month, date.Day);
}
```

If I am however wrong, please let me know. I really would like to have this solved.

Answer (score 2):

What rashleighp suggested is almost correct but does not work for e.g. adding 1 month to 2016-02-29 (result should be 2016-03-31) or 2017-02-28 (result should be 2017-03-31)

This modified version should work including all special cases.

```
public static DateTime AddMonthsCustom(this DateTime source, int months)
{
    var firstDayOfTargetMonth = new DateTime(source.Year, source.Month, 1).AddMonths(months);
    var lastDayofSourceMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(source.Year, source.Month);
    var lastDayofTargetMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(firstDayOfTargetMonth.Year, firstDayOfTargetMonth.Month);

    var targetDay = source.Day > lastDayofTargetMonth ? lastDayofTargetMonth : source.Day;
    if (source.Day == lastDayofSourceMonth)
        targetDay = lastDayofTargetMonth;

    return new DateTime(
        firstDayOfTargetMonth.Year, 
        firstDayOfTargetMonth.Month, 
        targetDay, 
        source.Hour, 
        source.Minute, 
        source.Second, 
        source.Millisecond, 
        source.Kind);
}
```

All NUnit tests below passed:

```
[TestCase("2017-01-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2016-12-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", 1)]
[TestCase("2017-02-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2016-12-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", 2)]
[TestCase("2017-03-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2016-12-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", 3)]
[TestCase("2016-03-28T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2016-02-28T01:01:01.0010000Z", 1)]
[TestCase("2016-03-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2016-02-29T01:01:01.0010000Z", 1)]
[TestCase("2017-03-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2017-02-28T01:01:01.0010000Z", 1)]
[TestCase("2016-02-29T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2016-01-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", 1)]
[TestCase("2017-02-28T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2017-01-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", 1)]
[TestCase("2016-12-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2017-01-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", -1)]
[TestCase("2016-12-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2017-02-01T01:01:01.0010000Z", -2)]
[TestCase("2016-12-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2017-03-31T01:01:01.0010000Z", -3)]
[TestCase("2016-02-28T01:01:01.0010000Z", "2016-03-28T01:01:01.0010000Z", -1)]
public void DateTimeExtensions_AddMonthsCustom(DateTime expected, DateTime dateTime, int months)
{
    // Arrange
    expected = expected.ToUniversalTime();
    dateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();

    // Act
    DateTime result = dateTime.AddMonthsCustom(months);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Kind, result.Kind);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No - it doesn't take that into account. It's custom code all the way!

Will your code only be interested in the last day of months, or do you want code to add a month to any date, but take into account when the date supplied is the last day of the month?

Comment: Yeah, the last day of the months would suffice as well I think...Ill mark the answer as soon as it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now, by checking if it is the last day of a month using *GetLastDayInCurrentMonth*. If thats the case, I use

```
DateTime nextMonth = date.AddDays(1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

If its not the last day, I just use AddMonths(1)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(yourDate.Day == DaysInMonth(yourDate.Year,yourDate.Month)) //check for last day
    yourDate.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(yourDate.Year,(yourDate.Month+1)%12));
```

Comment: What if your date is in december?

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: Thanks for spotting that out. check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime AddMonthsCustom(this DateTime source, int months)
    {
        DateTime result = source.AddMonths(months);
        if (source.Day != DateTime.DaysInMonth(source.Year, source.Month))
            return result;

        return new DateTime(result.Year, result.Month,
                            DateTime.DaysInMonth(result.Year, result.Month),
                            result.Hour, result.Minute, result.Second,
                            result.Millisecond, result.Kind);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It can add as many months as you like as an extension method -- i.e. `dateDue.AddSmarthMonths(6);` -- and considers any day of January after 28 "the last day of the month".

```
    public static DateTime AddSmartMonths(this DateTime d, int nMonths)
    {
        int year = d.Year;
        int month = d.Month;
        int day = d.Day;

        if ((day == 30) && (day < DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)))
            d = d.AddDays(1);
        else if ((month == 1) && (day > 28))
            d = new DateTime(year, month, 31);

        return d.AddMonths(nMonths);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
private void datTimPkerFrom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int DaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(datTimPkerFrom.Value.Year, datTimPkerFrom.Value.Month);

    if (DaysInMonth == 31)
    {
        datTimPkerTo.Value = datTimPkerFrom.Value.AddDays(30);
    }
    else if (DaysInMonth == 30)
    {
        datTimPkerTo.Value = datTimPkerFrom.Value.AddDays(29);
    }
    else if (DaysInMonth == 29)
    {
        datTimPkerTo.Value = datTimPkerFrom.Value.AddDays(28);
    }
    else
    {
        datTimPkerTo.Value = datTimPkerFrom.Value.AddDays(27);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add numMonths to someDate and, if someDate is end-of-month, return value will be end-of-month, otherwise it just does AddMonths(numMonths)

```
private DateTime AddMonthsRetainingEOM(DateTime someDate, int numMonths)
    {
        if (someDate.AddDays(1).Day == 1)
        {
            // someDate is EOM
            someDate = someDate.AddMonths(numMonths);
            // keep adding days if new someDate is not EOM
            while (someDate.AddDays(1).Day != 1)
            {
                someDate = someDate.AddDays(1);
            }
            return someDate;
        }
        else
        {
            // not EOM - Just add months
            return someDate.AddMonths(numMonths);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gives the last day in the next month in one line:

```
var t1 = new DateTime(2010,2,28); 
var t2 = t1.AddDays((t1.Day * -1) + 1).AddMonths(2).AddMilliseconds(-1).Date;
// t2: {31.03.2010 00:00:00}
```

(The operations are: get first day of current month (= 1.Feb 10), Add 2 Months (= 1. Apr 10), Subtract by 1 ms (= 31. Mar 10), Optional cutoff Time

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned extension method will yield the last day of month in case if the given date is last day of the month otherwise as it's in datetime API.

```
public static DateTime AddMonthsE(this DateTime value,int numberOfMonths)
{           
    bool isEndDate = DateTime.DaysInMonth(value.Year, value.Month) == value.Day;
    if(isEndDate)
    {
        var newDateTime = value.AddMonths(numberOfMonths);
        return new DateTime(newDateTime.Year, newDateTime.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(newDateTime.Year, newDateTime.Month));
    }
    return value.AddMonths(numberOfMonths);
}
```

**Input**  2/28/2010 12:00:00 AM 
**Output**  plus 1 months 3/31/2010 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
int numberofmonths = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); //number of target months as integer
dateTimePicker1.Text = DateTime.Parse(strDate).Date.AddMonths(numberofmonths).ToString("d"); //new date displayed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you´re trying to get always the same day in the next month, wouldn't it be simplier to use:

DateTime nextMonth = new DateTime(thisMonth.Year, thisMonth.Month + 1, thisMonth.Day);

Comment: I think where this falls apart is if the next month has fewer days than the current month has. Ex: thisMonth = Jan 30. There is no Feb 30, so you would throw an exception from the DateTime constructor there.

Comment: Also throws exception if it wraps around from December to January

Answer (score -1):

Try overloading the day property and setting it to 32. Whgen this is done in JavaScript, I believe it defaults back to the last day of whatever month you're in.

Comment: If you mean *set* the day property - it is immutable (this is C# - see the tags on the question).

Comment: Woah! Sorry. I didn't realise you couldn't do that in C#.